# Programatically switch betwen WiFi networks in .NET CF?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is it possible to switch between WiFi networks in WM 6 and .NET CF v3.5 ?

I'm writing a .NET Compact Framework v3.5 app for a Windows Mobile 6 device. I'd like to be able to switch between 2 different WiFi networks via C#. The first network is an Ad-Hoc wireless network with another device close by, and the second network is any other available WiFi network as configured in the Windows Mobile device (usually it will be a public/corporate WiFi with a known SSID)

The scenario I'm after is to do the following via C#/.NET code on the windows mobile device:

1. Establish Ad-Hoc WiFi connection to another device
2. Communicate with other device for a while
3. Drop the Ad-Hoc connection and check if there's another WiFi network available that has public Internet access (i.e. can I get a reply from http://www.google.com or something like that)
4. Connect to the available network in the previous step #3
5. Send/receive some data over the public internet
6. Drop the "public" network and reconnect to the Ad-Hoc network from step #1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/) has a class for handling wireless networks.  Look for the `OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace, and the `WirelessNetworkInterface` class.